# An ant starts from the original point (0, 0) of coordinate.

Tags: probability, set-partition

An ant starts from the origin of a coordinate system, $(0, 0)$, and in each step moves either up or right by one unit.  After $10$ such moves, what is the probability that the ant settles down at point $(4, 6)$?

I understand that it's a partition problem.  Because probability for either up or right is $1/2$ and the ant has to make $6$ moves up and $4$ to the right, would it be ${10 \choose 4} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^6 = {10 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{10} = 0.2051$?

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me.

Comment: If you draw the positive-positive quadrant of the Cartesian plane, and label each integer lattice point $(m, n)$ with the *number* of ways to arrive at that point after $m+n$ steps, you get Pascal's triangle (that is, the binomial coefficients), anchored at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  And here's a figure that may help you visualize your solution.

[image]